# An error occurred while formatting the event document (Detailed Message: The XSL style sheet for event type WorkItemChangedEvent could not be found.)

Tags: tfs

While upgrade TFS 2013 update 2 to TFS 2013 Update 4 we used wrong installation file (wrong lang package). When we found uot this, we uninstall TFS 2013 and install TFS 2013 Update 4 with correct language package.
After that notification messages send to users in xml format with header of post message:

> Subject: Work Item Changed: Bug XXXXXX - Do not work e-mail
>   notifications
>
> > An error occurred while formatting the event document (Detailed
> >     Message: The XSL style sheet for event type WorkItemChangedEvent could
> >     not be found.). Original Event Document:

In application tier, under "Data Tier Summary" when I click "Installed updates" I find wron update package (with wrong language)

Is there any way to uninstall Update 4 package beside restoring DB from backup?
Or other way to correct notifications?

Answer (score 0):

You need to raise a support call with Microsoft. They will be able to fix this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I did. After a small experience in determining settings, I mentioned that refer to template folder was wrong. In my case I just copy templates and give folder right name which pointed in settings of DB.